# What is the cardinality of the set of all binary trees defined over the natural numbers?

Tags: set-theory, computer-science, cardinals

I've been wondering what the cardinality of all binary trees would be?

Let me define binary trees to be clear. I am using an inductive definition :

The set $B(\mathbb{N})$ of binary trees over the natural numbers is defined as follows :

1. $\epsilon$ is the empty tree and $\epsilon \in B$
2. if $l \in B$ and $r \in B$ and $v \in \mathbb{N}$ then $(l, v, b) \in B$

I have a feeling it is uncountable.

To prove that it is uncountable I would have to somehow conjure up Cantor's diagonalization argument.

At first, I tried listing all traversals of one kind, say preorder traversals. I found out very quickly that this would not work. For any one traversal, there exists more than one binary tree.

I'm not even sure that the set is uncountable, I just have a very strong feeling.

Is there any standard technique on how to talk about the cardinality of inductively defined sets that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your definition to show there are only countably many such binary trees for every given size $n$ using induction. Let $B_n$ be the set of binary trees on $n$ vertices. The case $n=0$ is clear, there is only one empty tree.

If $n>0$ then for any given $v\in \mathbb{N}$ there are most
$$  \left| \bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1}  B_i \times B_{n-1-i}\right|  $$
binary trees of the form $(l,r,v)$ with $n$ vertices as you describe. This is countably many, and so ranging over all $v$ we get that $|B_n|$ is countable.

Then the total number is $|B_1\cup B_2 \cup\ldots |$, a countable union of countable sets, which is countable

Comment: Very interesting, thank you! 
Also, in general, wouldn't the set of any "inductively-defined finite objects" always be countable? Because this argument seems very generalizable.

Comment: Also, we took the set $\mathbb{N}$, but what if instead of $v \in \mathbb{N}$ I had defined binary trees over the real numbers, so that $v \in \mathbb{R}$? Will this argument still work? I have a feeling it won't. Intuitively, I feel the set $B_n$ won't be countable then for any $n$!

Comment: @RahulChhabra Indeed the argument can generalize to many cases but be careful! I let $v$ range over all $\mathbb{N}$ and use the fact that countable union of countable sets is countable. If $v\in \mathbb{R}$ then already there are uncountably many trees of the form $(\epsilon, v,\epsilon)$, namely as many as $|\mathbb{R}|$

Comment: @RahulChhabra Also, I am not so sure about part 2. in your recursive definition. Don't we also require that $l$ and $r$ are disjoint and both don't contain $v$?

Comment: why might we require $l$ and $r$ to be disjoint? The tree $((\epsilon,1,\epsilon),1, (\epsilon,1,\epsilon))$ is very much supposed to be a valid binary tree and if we add disjointness and "niether contains $v$" then this will become invalid.

Comment: yes precisely. We can't even establish the base case of the induction! 
Even though I do see a pattern - let us call the set we are constructing our trees over the "alphabet". If our alphabet is countable then we get a countable set of trees. If our alphabet were a finite set, it is very clear that all trees constructed on it also form a countable set. 
It would be really nice if setting our alphabet to $\mathbb{R}$ creates a set of trees with cardinality of the continuum, I will explore this!